# Running simple code with AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine

I recently started to learn about AndEngine ,but I am having troubles running it .I am learning tutorials about the basics and I want to load a `png image` ,but it`s giving me errors and the project is failing.

**Here is the source code**

```java
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {
    protected static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 460;
    BitmapTextureAtlas playerTexture;
    ITextureRegion playerTexureRegion;
    Scene scene;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Camera mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions engine = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(WIDTH, HEIGHT), mCamera);

        return engine;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        loadsfx();
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
    }

    private void loadsfx() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("assets/");

        playerTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(),64,64);
        playerTexureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(playerTexture, this, "fred1.png",0,0);
        playerTexture.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0,125,58));

        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions pEngineOptions) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.onCreateEngine(pEngineOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene, OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Sprite sPlayer = new Sprite(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, playerTexureRegion, this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sPlayer.setRotation(45.0f);
        this.scene.attachChild(sPlayer);
        pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
    }
```

here is what the LogCat is saying

```
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:315)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:289)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.source.AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.onLoadBitmap(AssetBitmapTextureAtlasSource.java:86)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas.writeTextureToHardware(BitmapTextureAtlas.java:154)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.opengl.texture.Texture.loadToHardware(Texture.java:137)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureManager.updateTextures(TextureManager.java:254)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onDrawFrame(Engine.java:613)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at org.andengine.opengl.view.EngineRenderer.onDrawFrame(EngineRenderer.java:105)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1363)
05-20 18:11:28.110: E/AndEngine(6616): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
```

Please help me I have a big desire to learn about the engine, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

```
BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath(path);
```

"setAssetBasePath" set assets path from "assets" directory. 
In your code full path to sprite image must be "/assets/assets/fred1.png". 
If path to sprite "/assets/fred1.png" simply delete `BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("assets/");`

Comment: Need more information about your resources. What is image size? Full path?  P.s. `this.scene.setBackground(new Background(0,125,58));` is wrong. Color value should be between 0.0 and 1.0, inclusive.

Comment: the image size is 3,10KB and it`s 64x64 png file.I`m trying to fix it all day and i`t s not working ,please somebody help me :(

Comment: This error mean that for some reason can not load your image. You can try `playerTexureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromSource(playerTexture, FileBitmapTextureAtlasSource.create(new File("assets/fred1.png")));`

Comment: Check whether fred1.png is actually getting included in your APK.  Easiest way to do this is to change its filename extension from .apk to .zip and open in Windows Explorer.  You should see an assets directory containing your file.  If you don't, then the problem is not with your code, it's with the packaging of your apk.